# can i store google native ad on array?

Tags: swift, admob, native-ads

i am using google Nativead on my collectionview, First i request for ad then i got five ad at a time then all ad are store in single array like

For example

```
var nativeAds = [GADUnifiedNativeAd]()

func adLoader(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader, didReceive nativeAd: GADUnifiedNativeAd) {

        nativeAds.append(nativeAd)
}
```

Then i am using this array on specific collectionview row for display Nativead.
But, my problem is my ad impression is too low around (35, 40)%, so, what i do for displaying Nativead in my collectionview. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you may add the object to the array when an ad is ready and reload the collection view
or you can add an item to the collection view when an ad is received using

```
collectionView.insertItems(at: <#[IndexPath]#>)
```

i think this will help you